# Make Font Awesome Icon Background Transparent

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

Currently I am working on a sample solution using icons from [Font Awesome's CDN](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css).

For some reason my icons are displaying with a white background. I noticed this when applying the `shadow` effect from `Bootstrap` in my `html`.

[image]

Really what I would like to see here is simply the fingerprint icon foreground and a transparent background.

HTML

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col ">
        <div>
              <span>
                  <i class="fas fa-fingerprint fa-5x shadow "></i>
              </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your CSS also please

Comment: then remove the 'shadow' class

Comment: You'll need to add shadow CSS as `text-shadow` as Font Awesome is actually a font.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up creating a `text-shadow` class in css and used that in my HTML to generate the the shadow effect.

HTML UPDATE

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col ">
        <div>
              <span>
                  <i class="fas fa-fingerprint fa-5x text-shadow "></i>
              </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Update

```
.text-shadow {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #20202088;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We have two kinds of shadows in CSS:

#### box-shadows

Shadows that work in block level (like the one you have used here)

#### text-shadow

Shadows that work in text level

it seems that bootstrap's `shadow` class only works in box level and you have to remove it and use custom CSS like this:

```
span i {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

'box-shadow' will put the shadow on the 'i' surrounding the icon not the icon itself.

As Font Awesome is a SVG font you will need to be using 'text-shadow'.

```css
.shadow {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #20202088;
}

.fa-fingerprint {
  color: #25b8f0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col ">
        <div>
              <span>
                  <i class="fas fa-fingerprint fa-5x shadow "></i>
              </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

Font Awesome is actually a font. So, we need to give the text-shadow. :)

```css
.fas { 
  color: orange; 
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #333 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col ">
    <div>
      <span><i class="fas fa-fingerprint fa-5x shadow" ></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```